# AutoContrast in Albumentations?

Tags: albumentations

Can I use AutoContrast in Albumentations library? That is, making the darkest pixel
black and lightest pixel white. I see the RandomBrightnessContrast one, but is it the right one when I select contrast parameter to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no ready-to-use transform for autocontrast now. You may implement it by yourself using [Lambda](https://albumentations.ai/docs/api_reference/augmentations/transforms/#albumentations.augmentations.transforms.Lambda) transform:

```
def _autocontrast(img):
    h = cv2.calcHist([img], [0], None, [256], (0, 256)).ravel()

    for lo in range(256):
        if h[lo]:
            break
    for hi in range(255, -1, -1):
        if h[hi]:
            break

    if hi > lo:
        lut = np.zeros(256, dtype=np.uint8)
        scale_coef = 255.0 / (hi - lo)
        offset = -lo * scale_coef
        for ix in range(256):
            lut[ix] = int(np.clip(ix * scale_coef + offset, 0, 255))

        img = cv2.LUT(img, lut)

    return img

transform = Lambda(image = lambda img: _autocontrast(img))
```

P.S. [Pull request](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations/pull/607) containing Autocontrast transform is under review for a long time. You may vote for this PR on github in order to highlight it to maintainers :)

Comment: After 6 months I finally have an answer xD thanks for your input. I will make a comment to the PR.